# Add additional namespace to SubSonic 2.2 generated files

Tags: subsonic, web-config, subsonic2.2

I think it should be possible to add additional namespaces to the generated classes without modifing SubSonic's core or the CS_ClassTemplate.aspx, but instead with a SubSonic config parameter. But atm I can't find any example.

Does anyone know how this config option (if any) is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this just using the config and there's no mention of it in the docs:

http://subsonicproject.com/docs/2.0_Configuration

Comment: Interesting. I didn't find the place where the default namespaces are inserted. Don't looks like it is in the template file. Probably some hard coded SubCommander magic. But adding a namespace to my template file workes fine, too! thx.